# How to highlight the selected item with image in DrawerLayout

Tags: xamarin.android, menuitem, drawerlayout

I am working on Xamarin. android where I need to highlight the selected item as in following image[image].

I can able to highlight the selected item as following.[image]

```
private async void OnMenuSelection(IMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        menuItem.SetCheckable(true);

    }
```

By adding `menuItem.SetCheckable(true)`  can able highlight but I need to add that blue color too at left hand side for selection.

Is there any way to do add such a way?

My layout is:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/questiontypes_nav_view"
  android:layout_width="220dp"
  android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_drawer_top"
  android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollbars="none"
      android:layout_above="@+id/navigation_drawer_bottom"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
      android:layoutDirection="ltr"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
  android:background="#031d2c"        
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:itemTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
  app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
  app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_drawable"
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_drawable">
```

Comment: what have you achieved so far? also add the drawer layout code as well as its template

Comment: Thanks for the response@G.hakim, so far I am able to highlight the selected item

Comment: Okay and what is left to do?